# PHP - MySQL Database shows up on webpage but with wrong information and in wrong spots

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

I have a database in MySQL, but the table isn't taking in the right information. For instance, When I run my code, the table I have in excel and now in MySQL automatically appear on my webpage, but the data is both wrong and almost all in the wrong spot. The only correct part is the player Number and Name are in the right spot, but even then, the entire name doesn't even show. then the position column is all random Letters, and then height is in weight, weight in age, and so on and so forth.

Also, My excel sheet has all the stuff correctly of course. I'm just not sure why when creating this database it's being fed wrong information

This is my entire PHP Code:

```
<?php        

     $db_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
     if (!$db_conn)
        die("Unable to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());  // die is similar to exit

     mysqli_query($db_conn, "CREATE DATABASE IF NO EXISTS bearsroster;");

     if (mysqli_query($db_conn, "CREATE DATABASE bearsroster;"))
        echo "Database ready<br>";
     else
        echo "Unable to create database: " . mysqli_error($db_conn) . "<br>";

    mysqli_select_db($db_conn, "bearsroster");

    $cmd = "CREATE TABLE sportDatabase (    number int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                            playerName char(50),
                                            position varchar(2),
                                            height char(3),
                                            weight int(3),
                                            age int(2),
                                            experience int(2),
                                            collegeName char(60)
                                        );";         //Creates the table
      mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

      $cmd = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bearsRoster.csv' INTO TABLE sportDatabase FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';";
      mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

      echo "<h1>football database contents</h1>";
      $cmd = "SELECT * FROM sportDatabase";
      $records = mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd); 

      echo( "<table border = 'black' align:'center'> 
                    <tr> 
                    <th>Number</th> 
                    <th>Player Name</th> 
                    <th>Position</th> 
                    <th>Height</th> 
                    <th>Weight</th> 
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Experience</th> 
                    <th>College Name</th>
                    </tr>" . PHP_EOL  );

     //Prints out the table
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
        echo( "<tr> 
                <td id = 'yellow'>" . $row['number'] . "</td> 
                <td id = 'red'>" . $row['playerName'] . "</td> 
                <td id = 'red'>" . $row['position'] . "</td> 
                <td id = 'blue'>" . $row['height'] . "</td>
                <td id = 'blue'>". $row['weight'] . "</td>
                <td id = 'blue'>". $row['age'] . "</td>
                <td id = 'pink'>". $row['experience'] . "</td>
                <td id = 'pink'>". $row['collegeName'] . "</td>

                </tr>". PHP_EOL );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first question that comes up is: What does `bearsRoster.csv` look like? Can we get an example row perhaps?

Comment: If you look directly in the MySQL tables what do you see? Have you tried validating your page with an HTML validator? You can view the source in a browser and copy it to an HTML validator to see if there are issues with your layout.

Comment: @kojow7 the MySQL table looks the same both on my webpage and in the localhost/phpmyadmin server.

Comment: Okay, so then since it is displayed incorrectly in phpmyadmin, then as ippi said your CSV file must not be correct. Have a look at that and verify that things are in the correct order.

Comment: @ippi i just took a picture of both my excel sheet and what it looks like on the html site. will find a way to upload that now

Comment: Stack Overflow does allow you to add images to your post.

Comment: I added an imgur link to the end of my post showing both pictures. the picture on top is the excel sheet that is the example the table should show up as @kojow7

Comment: Are there any commas in your player names? Like `Andersson, Peter`? Position is random letters you say, and only that column is varchar?  I would try forcing charset in `CREATE TABLE` `position varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8,`

Comment: The problem is the commas in your name column. When you save from Excel to CSV there are some options to add quotes around some of the fields. Make sure you choose this option.

Comment: @ippi i thought that might be the issue so i changed it to this and still no change - `number int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                                playerName varchar(50),
                                                position varchar(2),
                                                height varchar(3),
                                                weight int(3),
                                                age int(2),
                                                experience int(2),
                                                collegeName varchar(60)`

Comment: Actually, I just checked on my version of Excel, and saving it as a CSV file worked correctly without needing to set any options. Are you sure you selected the correct CSV file type when you were saving?

Comment: Try opening the CSV file in notepad (or other text editor) and have a look at what it really looks like.

Comment: I made the excel sheet on google doc and downloaded from there. there's only one .csv option. I also tried using copying it to an excel sheet and saving without google docs and its the same thing, no other options and nothing i can change

Comment: I just opened on notepad this is the first 2 lines, all others are following this pattern : 49,"Acho, Sam",LB,6-3,260,28,7,Texas
38,"Amos, Adrian",DB,6-0,214,24,3,Penn State

Comment: so in that order, it has number, name, position, height, weight, age, experience, and college, as its supposed to

Comment: I think you may need to add the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` option to your `LOAD DATA` line. That's a double quote inside a single quote.

Comment: Where in that line would I add that though? like specifically after what word in the line

Comment: @richardjames Have a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html - try something out, if you are still stuck let us know. You will probably also need to use the keyword `OPTIONALLY` as not all of your fields are enclosed by quotes.